# Linux update roundcube stops working and poiting to squirrelmail

Tags: php, linux, apache, roundcube, squirrelmail

I'm trying to solve a problem with Roundcube. On monday I was updating server and installing php 7.1.5 (Debian 8 with ISPConfig) manual: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/. It seems that php and everyting else is working except Roundcube webmail.

Users started complaining that they cannot acces Roundcube webpage with error: `ERROR: Config file "config/config.php" not found. You need to configure SquirrelMail before you can use it.` Like what? I'm not using Squirrelmail. What I find out was that there was missing config file for roundcube in apache2/conf-enabled, so I created annother one with `alias` poiting to `/usr/share/roundcube`.

Config file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/roundcube.conf

```
Alias /roundcube /usr/share/roundcube
Alias /webmail /usr/share/roundcube

<Directory /usr/share/roundcube>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 # AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 AddType text/x-component .htc

 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
 php_flag display_errors Off
 php_flag log_errors On
 # php_value error_log logs/errors
 php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
 php_value post_max_size 12M
 php_value memory_limit 64M
 php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
 php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
 php_flag magic_quotes_runtime Off
 php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
 php_flag suhosin.session.encrypt Off
 #php_value session.cookie_path /
 php_flag session.auto_start Off
 php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 21600
 php_value session.gc_divisor 500
 php_value session.gc_probability 1
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ skins/larry/images/favicon.ico
 # security rules:
 # - deny access to files not containing a dot or starting with a dot
 # in all locations except installer directory
 RewriteRule ^(?!installer)(\.?[^\.]+)$ - [F]
 # - deny access to some locations
 RewriteRule ^/?(\.git|\.tx|SQL|bin|config|logs|temp|tests|program\/(include|lib|localization|steps)) - [F]
 # - deny access to some documentation files
 RewriteRule /?(README\.md|composer\.json-dist|composer\.json|package\.xml)$ - [F]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 </IfModule>

 FileETag MTime Size

 <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
 Options -Indexes
 </ifModule>

 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/roundcube/plugins/enigma/home>
 Options -FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/roundcube/config>
 Options -FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/roundcube/temp>
 Options -FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/roundcube/logs>
 Options -FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>
```

If I type wrong alias, I get 404, sor alias is working poiting to that directory, but then.. Huh.. Also I winf another roundcube folder in roundcube folder /usr/share/roundcube/roundcube with exactly same code like in parent  with time matching to Linux update / php installation.

IMAP is working. Just Rouncube part is messed up.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. For others with same problem:

There was a symlink in `/usr/share/squirrelmail -> roundcube`, so when I ran `apt-get upgrade` the system wrote new squirrelmail files to roundcube folder and rewrited `index.html` (error from my first post: `ERROR: Config file "config/config.php" not found. You need to configure SquirrelMail before you can use it.`), so after typing `<server-ip>/webmail` it was trying to run unconfigured squirrelmail from roundcube folder so it was "masking" itself :)

I was unaware of this symlink (I haven't installed that server) and after downloading propriete version of roundcube and copying files to `/usr/share/roundcube` (+ plus deleting squirrelmail files) the roundcube started working again properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have upgraded to PHP 7 right?
So this directive will be ignored by PHP 7: `<IfModule mod_php5.c>`
Try to change it to this: `<IfModule mod_php7.c>`

Comment: Good point. Yes, I have upgraded to PHP 7. I have to rewrite this later. I've solved the problem. See my latest post (I have been writing right now).